# Comparing two tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to pull AD information in my database and compare it with my MSP program to see what PCs are in AD but not in our system. To do that I need to get a list of the computers in the AD integration table and compare it to the computers table in our MSP system. I have been trying to get this working for the last couple hours and cannot find a solution despite my research. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Below is the code I am using.

```
SELECT `computers`.`ClientID` AS `clientid`
, `computers`.`LastUsername` as `Username`
, `plugin_ad_entries`.`DomainGUID` AS `domainguid`
, `plugin_ad_computers`.`OS`
, `plugin_ad_computers`.`LogonCount`
, `plugin_ad_computers`.`LastLogon`
, `plugin_ad_entries`.`Name` as `ComputerName`
, `plugin_ad_entries`.`WhenChanged` as `ChangedDate`
, `plugin_ad_entries`.`WhenCreated` as `CreatedDate` 
from `plugin_ad_computers` 
JOIN `plugin_ad_entries` ON `plugin_ad_computers`.`ObjectGUID` = 
`plugin_ad_entries`.`ObjectGUID` 
JOIN `plugin_ad_domains` ON `plugin_ad_entries`.`DomainGUID` = 
`plugin_ad_domains`.`ObjectGUID`  
LEFT JOIN `computers` ON `computers`.`Name` = `plugin_ad_entries`.`Name`
```

The first problem I am having is that I am recieving duplicates in the query for PCs that have the same name.

The second problem is that for the PCs that are not in my system my ClientId column is nulled out.

Comment: the clientid will be NULL since you said those are not on your system which the LEFT JOIN is suppose to be doing. for duplicates, check those duplicates and check the column where they differ

Comment: Well, I am able to pull all of the computers from a client by not doing a left join and changing it to a join to obtain the clientID. This is most likely because it just copys the client ID to everyone. I have got to be able to do that for the clientID column only and look for the user account with a left join. Does that make sense? I am not a heavy SQL scripter, just been modifying code found on this site and others.

Comment: Okay. I am now looking for a different option to do what I want. My goal is to create a column that outputs 1 if a computer name exists in another table all while matching the clientID. This is what I am trying. SELECT customcolumn = (Select Name from plugin_ad_entries where name in (select name from computers where clientID= plugin_ad_entries.clientID))